# How to find maximal value of an array?

Tags: php, arrays

How do I get the largest value of an array?

Comment: [`max($array)`](http://php.net/max)

Comment: Let's give him the benefit of the doubt here.  If he realized that max was the function, he wouldn't have needed to google.

Answer (score 9):

The `max($values)` function <sup>[[php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php)]</sup> will return the numerically greatest value from an array of numbers and/or strings.

```
max(array(5, 3, 13, 495, 13, 84, 99, '134', 11))
= 495
```

```
max(array(0, '1024', 512, '#24564'))
= '1024'
```

```
$values = array(
    5 => 5,
    "130" => 10,
    "15" => 90,
     9999 => 50
);

max($values)
= 90
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need an algorithm and not a built-in function, you could try something like this (in Javascript, since it's pretty simple to read):

```
function find_max(array) {
    var max = -9999999; // some arbitrarily low value
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
       if (array[i] > max)
           max = array[i];
    return max;
}
```

Hope that helps. Good luck :)